# Whoosh groupping by time interval

Tags: whoosh

I have the following structure and is indexed using Whoosh.

```
timestamp            name  count(b.name)
-------------------  ----  -------------
2010-11-16 10:32:22  John  2
2010-11-16 10:35:12  John  7
2010-11-16 10:36:34  John  1
2010-11-16 10:37:45  John  2
2010-11-16 10:48:26  John  8
2010-11-16 10:55:00  John  9
2010-11-16 10:58:08  John  2
```

I want to make a query to get the following structures, so it displays name frequency every 5 mins

```
timestamp            name  count(b.name)
-------------------  ----  -------------
2010-11-16 10:30:00  John  2
2010-11-16 10:35:00  John  10
2010-11-16 10:40:00  John  0
2010-11-16 10:45:00  John  8
2010-11-16 10:50:00  John  0
2010-11-16 10:55:00  John  11
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to introduce additional field into index e.g. timestamp_trimmed, trim timestamp to 5min interval and save into timestamp_trimmed field and perform search with grouped by timestamp_trimmed field.